# Segmented Control with one tableview.How to remove the "Load More" cell which i added manually in the tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I add a "Load More" cell in the `tableview` through check if the current cell is the last one.

but i have got 2 kinds of data to display,so i used a `UISegmentedControl` to switch.
once at the first tab of `UISegmentedControl`,the "Load More" cell appears at the last cell.but when i switch to second tab of the `UISegmentedControl`.The "Load More" cell still stays there...and there is still a "Load More" cell at the last of `tableview`.so there are 2 "Load More" cell shows.

i want to remove the first "Load More" cell,but i dont know how.Much THX.
[image]

EDIT:

```
static NSString * ID = @"TopicCustomCellIdentifier";

    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:ID];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ID];        

    if(IS_LAST_TOPIC_ROW){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ID];
        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ID];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Load More";
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.imageView.image = nil;                      
        return cell;
    }

    MTopicItem *topic;
    cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    if(SEGMENTINDEX == 0){
        topic = [_my_topics_data_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else{
        topic = [_rec_topics_data_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:topic.name];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];        

    if(IS_RETINA){
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: topic.image]
                                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default50"]];
    }else{
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: topic.sImage]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default"]];        
    }
    topic = nil;
    return cell;


#define IS_LAST_TOPIC_ROW ((indexPath.row == [_my_topics_data_array count] - 1) && [_my_topics_data_array count] != 0) || ((indexPath.row == [_rec_topics_data_array count] - 1) && [_rec_topics_data_array count] != 0)

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(SEGMENTINDEX == 0){
        return [_my_topics_data_array count];
    }else{
        return [_rec_topics_data_array count];
    }
}
```

Comment: add your - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath code for reference;

Comment: check IS_LAST_TOPIC_ROW is same in 1 & 2 segment,reset IS_LAST_TOPIC_ROW in secont segment

Comment: could u tell me how to check and how to reset...sorry,im a newb.

Comment: show me the no.of rows mehthods

Comment: do you mean "numberOfRowsInSection:"?ive update question.thx.

Comment: add one bool value to check segment 1 & 2,it like if(IS_LAST_TOPIC_ROW && flag), if 1st seg flag=yes; else flag = no;

Answer (score 0):

Use the reloadData to refresh the view on segment touch.

```
[myTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a row manually, you can delete that manually too:

```
deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a):

Answer (score 0):

Check the last cell text label is load more don't add in second control.

Comment: also check by total rows with indexpath.row if same don't add load more.

Comment: the problem is not to add the second load more or not,it's how to remove the first load more.

Comment: do you mean "numberOfRowsInSection:"?ive update question.thx.

Answer (score 0):

- keep a boolean to make sure when to show the cell or not.
- Check it before you add the loadmore cell in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`
  method .
- Also the `numberOfRowsInSection` should be maintained with the same
  bool.
- When you click the `loadmore cell` set boolean to no and then reload table

How it looks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  if(showLoadMore)
  {
    if(IS_LAST_TOPIC_ROW){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ID];
        if(cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ID];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Load More";
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.imageView.image = nil;                      
        return cell;
    }
  }

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  if(showLoadMore{
     return [_my_topics_data_array count]+1;
  }
  else
  {
     return [_my_topics_data_array count];
  }
}
```

Comment: IS_LAST_TOPIC_ROW makes the last row index for you ,yeah a boolean indicating the loadmore should be shown

Comment: thx,but i dont understand what to get variable showLoadMore.and,you could keep clicking loadMore all the way to load more and more.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to the reusing of cell. When you deque a cell from the tableview check if it is not `nil` and reset content.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ID];
if(cell) {
    cell.textLabel.text=@"";
    cell.imageView.image=nil;
}
```

Also cross check if `IS_LAST_TOPIC_ROW` is identifying the last row correctly.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

just now,i suddenly got the answer.
I write 2 CONSTANT:

```
#define IS_LAST_MY_TOPIC_ROW (indexPath.row == [_my_topics_data_array count] - 1) && [_my_topics_data_array count] != 0

#define IS_LAST_REC_TOPIC_ROW (indexPath.row == [_rec_topics_data_array count] - 1) && [_rec_topics_data_array count] != 0
```

and in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

```
if(SEGMENTINDEX == 0){
        if(IS_LAST_MY_TOPIC_ROW){
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Load More";
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
            cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            cell.imageView.image = nil;
            return cell;
        }

        topic = [_my_topics_data_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else{
        if(IS_LAST_REC_TOPIC_ROW){
            cell.textLabel.text = @"加载更多";
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
            cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            cell.imageView.image = nil;
            return cell;
        }
        topic = [_rec_topics_data_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```